# Java EE Security Roles in the EJB Container and how they Propagate From and/or Relate to the Web Container

Tags: security, jsf, jakarta-ee, java-ee-6, jdbcrealm

I did a test the other day on an app I'm working on. I wanted to see how the security propagated from web tier to Java EE container. I wrote a quick couple of pages, a backing bean and an EJB stateless bean to do this. I set it up so I could log in and check what the principal and roles I was in on the web tier and on the EJB container.

The call to the EJB context said that I had the same principal as the call through the Faces Context. However, while the web tier reported (getRole) confirmed as expected that I was in the groups set up in the database, the call to the EJB side failed and raised an exception. Basically it said it could find there were no groups like I was asking it about configured in its context. And indeed, I have done no security configuration on the EJB side.

I seem to missing something here. What do I need in order make sure that both sides are in sync in terms of roles/groups. I have configured the web side such that it maps the users to groups via the JDBC realm (that is not custom that is a standard configuration option).

Note that I am on Glassfish 3.1.1 and I created a customized JDBC Realm to match my groups to my users in what I think is a cleaner way (i.e. using a lookup table in between). FWIW, I have been around in software for a long while, but just getting used to full stack Java EE (about a year).